# Android:Retrieve Intent data in service?

Tags: android

Hi I am passing an intent with some data to start a service but I am unable to retrieve my strings ,as my `OnCreate()` method of the Service is called first and I have all the work in it but I am not able to retrieve intent data in this method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intent extras are for use with commands (`onStartCommand()`), or possibly with requests to bind (`onBind()`). There is no `Intent` associated with simply creating the service.

Rewrite your service to do the work that is customized by the `Intent` extras in `onStartCommand()` or `onBind()`. Or, consider whether `Intent` extras are the right approach to use -- for example, I would expect that things a `Service` needs all of the time would be available in a database or `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: i used onStart method and put all my code inside it bt the button that calls the service stucks up until my file is uploded on the server i.e until the service completes.

Comment: @Harinder: Then you should be using a background thread somewhere, probably inside of the service. Perhaps consider creating an `IntentService` instead of a regular `Service`.